# VBA. Sum until a certain criteria is met and then count the rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm basically trying to count/Select the rows whithin the range between a row that in the B column contains an "S" and until in the E column sum up to 1 like in this image

[image: example1]

Here's what i have tried so far

```
Dim rcount, lastcol, lastrow, lastrow1, sumLimit, Count, endcount As Long
Dim i, e, a As Integer
Dim strB, strB1 As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

With ActiveSheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastcol = ws.Cells("3", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    lastcol0 = ws.Cells("3", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    rcount = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = rcount To 2 Step -1
            strB = Left(.Cells(i, "B").Value, 1)
            If strB = "S" Then
                sumLimit = 1: ws.Range("A1").Activate
                For a = rcount To lastrow Step 1
                    Count = Count + ws.Range("E" & a).Value
                    If Count >= sumLimit Then
                        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E" & a): Exit For
                    End If
                Next a
                rng.Select
                'endcount = rng.Rows.Count
                For e = 1 To endcount Step 1
                    .Cells(i + e, lastcol).Value = Cells(i, lastcol0) * Cells(i + e, lastcol0)
                Next e
            Else
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

I've tried to use this part of the code from another post but couldn't make it work

```
sumLimit = 1: ws.Range("A1").Activate
                For a = rcount To lastrow Step 1
                    Count = Count + ws.Range("E" & a).Value
                    If Count >= sumLimit Then
                        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E" & a): Exit For
                    End If
                Next a
                rng.Select
```

Comment: FYI `ws.Cells("3",` should really be `ws.Cells(3,`   The first one works, but it's not regular usage.

Comment: In your code `rcount` = `lastrow`, so `For a = rcount To lastrow Step 1` will go for only 1 iteration. This means `rng` is never set, which means `rng.Select` should raise an object-not-defined error. I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, but try `For a = 2 To lastrow Step 1`

Comment: Or maybe `For a = i To lastrow Step 1`

Comment: Please share a relevant screenshot where we can see what you are trying to sum up and where the results should be returned or what needs to be selected or...

Comment: @SuperSymmetry you're right i should have  `For a = i To lastrow Step 1` but what i want to achive is to obtain the number of rows in column E that are after a row that starts with an "S" in this case row 22 and that by summing the quantities in those subsequent cells they keep adding up to 1, in this case the answer would be 3 or the cells E23:E25 would be selected, i only want them selected because of the visual representation what i want to define is this `endcount = rng.Rows.Count` so endcount = 3

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I want the number of rows from i + 1 to when the subsequents cells in E sum 1, this would stop at 3 because 40 would sum more than 1